# Processing Outlook Custom Forms in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook, outlook-2010

In MS Outlook I created few custom forms.
Is is possible in C# to access and change these forms?
I was searching Web for an example, but couldn't find. 
Can someone point me to one?
Thanks
zb

Answer (score 0):

Custom forms is a relatively old technology for customizing the OUtlook UI. If you develop VSTO based add-in I'd recommend creating form regions instead. See [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx) for more information.